# Pros and cons of a pull-push propeller configuration

Tags: propeller, thrust

What are the pros and cons of a pull push propeller in comparison to a counter rotating propeller?[image]

Comment: By counter rotating do you mean both in pull configuration?

Comment: And by counterrotating, do you mean one propeller immediately behind the other as in some later P51 configurations?

Comment: On an ultralight? I would think biggest CON is the weight of a structure to hold all that mass, vs small engines just on the wing.  Someone a while back, and I can't find a picture of it, had a small plane with small twin engines, that had a very open canopy, intended for nature shoots.  Drawing a blank on the name of it. Was an interesting design.

Comment: Take a look at some of the configurations here [1]  [1]:https://www.google.com/search?q=ultralight+twin&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=ZEBebWpSkIfB-M%253A%252CD5pyd5RCZYONLM%252C_&usg=__gp48hX2PiFstvq7ZxNFUl9iDHqc%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH-oqStY3bAhVDq1MKHY9BDMAQ9QEIpQEwBg#imgrc=ZEBebWpSkIfB-M:  I think I might be thinking of the Red & Yellow pusher in the 4th row  [Air-Cam][2], that's the one  https://www.pilotmix.com/images/ac_images/crop/optimized/385_886eb87452a5cacaed28104680a83b63.jpg  [2]: http://www.aircam.com

Comment: center of gravity is a serious concern, too.

Comment: Is nobody going to comment on that registration...?

Comment: don't know about the general concept, but looking at the photo, I wouldn't want to fly something with center of thrust and center of mass so high.

Answer (score 3):

Pusher-puller multi engine vs single or multi engine contra rotating propellers:

**Pros:**

- Ideal configuration for a multi engine aircraft as it eliminates thrust asymmetry in the event of an engine failure.
- As a consequence, improves safety during takeoff, landing and low speed, low altitude flight.
- Can be a useful arrangement for multi engine flying boats.
- Does not require oppositely geared engines nor heavy gearboxes.

**Cons:**

- Engine crankshaft on the A/C centerline requires a more unorthodox airframe to accommodate which can present additional design challenges.
- Does not fully eliminate propeller slipstream yaw depending on the aircraft layout.
- Does not eliminate or reduce yaw from P-Factor.
- Can be noisier inside the cabin than a twin with wing mounted engines.
- Aft mounted Engine can be more difficult to cool due to indirect ram airflow.
- Disrupted airflow from fwd propeller reduces the efficiency of the aft propeller.

Comment: You might want to add the lower efficiency of the rear propeller in a tandem configuration (when both are running), because it works in flow accelerated already by the forward propeller. This is especially noticeable at low speed.

Answer (score 1):

A push-pull arrangement with a "puller" propellor in front of a "pusher" can give rise to problems of aerodynamic interference with the rear propellor at higher power levels, this was a problem with the Dornier 335 fighter.

Comment: "can give rise to problems of aerodynamic interference with the rear propeller at higher power levels"......the engine to be used is 6.5hp...will there still be aerodynamic interference?

Comment: Assuming that you're talking about a microlight aircraft or something similar, I would not expect serious problems. The Dornier 335 had two Daimler Benz DB603 engines with 1800 to 2000 hp each.

Comment: "aerodynamic interference with the rear propellor" - could you please be more precise? Any sources?

Comment: Offhand, I can't be too precise but if you think about it, a tractor propellor creates spiral pressure waves behind it and this will affect the functioning of the pusher propellor when it's blades intercept these pressure waves. If nothing else, the efficiency of the pusher propellor may be reduced. In the Dornier 335, the situation was complicated by the fact that the pusher propellor was mounted slightly higher than the front tractor propellor.

Comment: The book Hitler's Luftwaffe by Tony Wood and Bill Gunston mentions the interference problem without going into more detail. I expect this would have taken the form of vibration and possibly fatigue induced failure if this was severe enough.