# How does washout increase static pitch stability in subsonic swept wings?

Tags: aerodynamics

How does washout increase static pitch stability in subsonic swept wings, more specifically in slow moving aircraft (eg. ultralights), 15mph to 60mph?

I understand washout is used to delay full stalls ( at least in unswept wings), but isn't pitch stability related to cg and centre of pressure?

See picture below of a european designed Archon SF1 rg ultralight with swept wings and retractable landing gear. Mid engine single prop is shown forward of the twin vertical tails.

[image: Archon SF1 rg]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the location of a propeller affect an aircraft's stability?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/77685/how-does-the-location-of-a-propeller-affect-an-aircrafts-stability)

Comment: Here is one who is not interested in motor glider-like fuel efficiency!  Re Zeus comment: if you have **retractable slats on a swept wing** you move your center of lift **back**, allowing **CG** to be further back.  When slats are retracted, you can **cruise without tail downforce** saving fuel.  The washout is opposite, so designing washout in a swept wing will move the center of lift forward.  The secret is that **center of lift on the WING generally moves forward with increasing AOA**  so a "horizontal stabilizer", something to counteract this, must be added.

Comment: @Manu H: I'm not asking about the affect of prop location on stability. The pic just shows the only ultralight that I know that has swept wings. I'm interested in finding out how to make swept wings more stable in pitch. I was told that washout helps. Just wasn't sure how that works.

Comment: @Fred-- many ultralights have swept wings-- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pterodactyl_Ascender -- note that variants have been flown with or without the canard-- the original Fledge/Pledge hang glider version had no canard-- undoubtedly this wing did have some washout--

Comment: related: [How does wing sweep increase aircraft stability?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9287/3394)

Comment: @Fred -- the discussion about whether the washout actually causes pitch stability, or just allows the CG to be moved forward, is a subtle one-- from the hang glider viewpoint we are sometimes interested in what happens if the aircraft goes weightless and the hang strap goes strap, effectively removing the pilot's weight from the picture-- this is when the pitch-up tendency delivered by washout is critical-- also for recovery from a very steep dive-- but I'm not saying any of the other answers are technically wrong--

Comment: @Fred -- all of the Rogallo-descended (but now highly evolved) swept or delta wings used on "trike" ultralights (basically a hang glider with a motor, seat, and wheels added) have very substantial washout, and it plays a key role in their pitch stability dynamics

Comment: (Make that "Pfledge" not "Pledge"!  Also "strap" (second occurence) should have been "slack")

Comment: @ quiet flyer: re trike ultralights- What is the typical angle of sweep and how much washout are you talking about? 2-3 deg? I understand on unswept wings, -1.5 deg washout is typical.

Comment: @Fred -- way more than 2-3 degrees of washout, I'm guessing at least 10.  Or maybe much more.  Maybe 20 or more.  Just a wild guess at present, haven't looked at drawing lately.  it's really pretty extreme.  See for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qA6pN1aeZ4 -- compare the angle of the metal rods at the tip, with the metal tube at the centerline.  What we would see in a trike ultralight might be similar.

Answer (score 2):

Since its earliest days during the pioneer era, washout on a swept wing has been accurately described as "putting the tail at the end of the wing." It works in exactly the same way as a tail stabilizer.

As long as the change in moment of the rear surface is greater than the change in moment of the forward surface the plane will be statically stable. It matters not whether the tail is inboard, outboard, moved ahead of the wing (as a canard), tacked on the end of a swept wing, or even tacked on the back of a straight wing in the form of a reflex trailing edge.

On a straight, unswept wing washout can delay the stall a little, but stalling is a complex subject and best treated separately.

Answer (score 1):

It works the same way as a tail, the wingtips are further aft, so the pitch **torque** around the center of gravity is greater.  $Torque$ = force x distance.

> Yes, pitch stability is related to CG and center of pressure

To create "static pitch stability", the **goal is to move the center of pressure further back with increasing AOA, which helps lower the nose**.  The most common way do this is to move weight forward and have a **down lifting** tail, but this is **not the only way**.

One can make lift nuetral, or even down lifting wing tips on swept wings. As AOA increases, lift here becomes increasingly positive.

So you can wash out the wing tips, and they will start pushing the nose down if AOA gets too high, just like a horizontal stabilizer/elevator does.

As AOA increases, tail "downforce" goes to 0 downforce, then to "upforce" lift, moving the center of pressure further and further back.  This  safeguards the wing from reaching stall AOA.

One of my mentors told me "the wing is the symphony, the tail is the conductor"
**With out a "tail", wing center of pressure typically moves forward with increasing AOA**, which is **"bad"**.

Comment: The 2nd paragraph is incorrect. The wing tips without washout (like the tail without decalage) would have even more nose-down moment (until they stall, but we are talking about normal flight). The point is that they actually provide (comparatively) nose-up moment, which allows to move CG forward, creating a stable configuration overall.

Comment: @Zeus ??? "They provide nose up moment, which allows to move CG forward"???  Isn't that what got Max into trouble?  Moving weight to solve an aerodynamic issue is "bad".  When u washout swept wings, lift is balanced with CG, lift moves **back, instead of forwards because of longer lever arm** at higher AOA.  In this respect, a longer fuselage and smaller downlifting tail is more efficient, with lower drag.  Washed out swept wings worked for Dunne, and are good for futuristic looking models, but do not allow for optimal wing AOA across the entire wing.

Comment: More scientificly put, if you wash out a swept wing **pitch down torque** increases as the longer **lever arm** of the wing tip begins to contribute lift force at a higher AOA. In the unstalled AOA range, increase in Coefficient of Lift is linear.  So, the center of lift moves back.  This is exactly what a properly designed H stab does,

Comment: @Zeus I think you mean to say the nose up moment from the washout creates a more trimmable configuration? I don't really see how washout affects stability (Cma) by a great deal.

Comment: Stability is not just an 'aerodynamic issue'; it's a balance issue as well. Pitch stability margin is the distance between CG and aerodynamic centre (or neutral point) for the whole aircraft. If you add washout or reduce tail AoA, _lift_ moves forward, of course (and it has to be balanced with CG). But I guess you wanted to say that lift _increase_ as AoA increases shifts back; this is equivalent to say that AC moves back. This is what I meant: now, with this arrangement, you can have CG in front of AC, which is the whole point.

Comment: @JZYL, this is all about swept wings. For them, washout has the same effect as lower AoA on the horizontal stabiliser, and it works for stability just the same way.

Comment: @Zeus Changing hstab angle hardly changes stability. It just shifts the Cm curve of the whole aircraft.

Comment: By itself, yes. This is why I started from CG and balance. This shifted Cm allows you to move CG and get a different stability picture.

Comment: If tail downforce changed to upforce, your stab wouldn't be leading edge down at low speed.  The slower you go, the higher the main wing AOA, for trim, the lower the stab's leading edge must go.  On no aircraft anywhere does the stab LE move up as you trim for a lower speed/higher AOA, which would have to happen if the tail was lifting up.  If the tail is making upforce, it means the C of G is aft of the Neutral Point and the tail lifting up to keep the nose from rising. This is an unstable condition.

Comment: But we could say "you change trim by using elevator to save stall", I'm working on preventing them in the first place.

Comment: Let's just say that if you remove the washout from my hang glider, I won't offer to test fly it  for you to see how it affected pitch stability.  Because I know it would have no pitch stability remaining at all.  And by the way I have verified that the washed-out tips create positive lift at low airspeed, and negative lift at high speed.  Just as does the horizontal tail of an aircraft with a moderately-far-aft CG location.

Comment: @quiet flyer Good comment, they "create lift at low airspeed" at higher AOA and "create negative lift at higher airspeeds" at lower AOA **just like a tail**.  The only issue of an uplifting tail vs a down lifting tail is (the same) uplifting tail stalls easier with increasing AOA.  Birds and XB-70s solve this by using a delta shaped "tail" that stalls at a much higher AOA.  So lifting tails are ok, as long as this parameter is under control.

Answer (score 1):

Washing out the outer span (i.e. decreasing the geometric incidence of the local section) of a swept wing does **not** directly increase the static stability of the aircraft (*see addendum*). The analysis mentions flying wing, but is applicable to any swept wing.

### 1. Stability

Static stability of a *low-speed* and *structurally rigid* flying wing is defined by having a negative variation of pitching moment with increasing angle of attack ($C_{m_\alpha}<0$), and is primarily achieved by the planform and the airfoil distribution:

- **Planform**: the swept outer span offsets the aerodynamic center aft, just like a traditional tail.
- **Airfoil**: the use of reflex airfoil allows for smaller unstable pitch variation at quarter chord, which further improves stability.

I'm going to skip why a negative pitching moment slope is necessary for static pitch stability, as this has been well discussed here ([e.g.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/47346/41375)). Since the swept portion is (hopefully) aft of the CG, washout acts like a tailplane incidence and plays very little into stability.

### 2. Trimmability

However, stability is not the only concern. Trimmability is the other (some may argue even more important) issue: at the desired wing lift (or angle of attack), we must ensure that the total pitching moment is zero. This is shown graphically below, where a fully trimmed state is point *A*:

[image: Static-pitch-stability]

*Image ref: Etkins, Dynamics of Flight*

Traditionally this is achieved via pitch surfaces such as tailplane incidence and elevators (by shifting the above $C_m$ curve up and down such that point *A* can lie at the desired angle of attack). For a flying wing, elevons can be put to use. But it's less effective due to shorter moment arm. If the pitching moment is too negative, we may run out of available elevons to trim or left to maneuver.

Help can come from two sources:

- **Airfoil**: reflex airfoil generally has positive pitching moment at zero angle of attack. This decreases the overall pitching moment of the wing.
- **Washout**: since the swept portion is (hopefully) aft of the CG, it effectively acts like a negative incidence on the tailplane, alleviating elevons travel.

With washout, a larger range of forward CG becomes possible due to elevons alleviation. This **indirectly** helps with stability if the static margin of available CG range had been too small without the proper washout.

### 3. Addendum

Since washout modifies the lift distribution on the wing, it changes the downwash on the outer span ($\frac{\partial{\epsilon}}{\partial{\alpha}}$), which does affect stability. However, this effect is secondary to what had been mentioned.

Comment: Washout has been used to achieve stability since 1904 and was a principal feature of the first certified stable aircraft, flown in 1910. It has been used for this purpose on many aircraft since. Your initial claim is wholly without foundation. Think of washout as adding a lateral element to the airfoil distribution - an aspect you have not addressed.

Comment: @Guy Have you even read my whole post?

Comment: You can qualify your claim with as much stuff as you care to, it does not alter that fact that "Washing out the outer span (i.e. decreasing the geometric incidence of the local section) of a swept wing does not directly increase the static stability of the aircraft" is just plain wrong. Adding that "washout acts like a tailplane incidence and plays very little into stability" implies that tailplanes contribute little to stability, which is equally wrong. And yes, if I had not read your post I would not have known that you fail to mention lateral redistribution of the airfoil.

Comment: @GuyInchbald Did I say tailplane does not affect stability? I'm pretty sure there's the word "incidence" somewhere in that sentence. "You can qualify your claim with as much stuff as you care to", so no matter how many equations or authoritative references I find, there's no convincing you?

Comment: Yep, you'll find the word "incidence" copied in my quote. But if you can find a reliable authority who claims that tailplane incidence does not affect pitch stability, I will find ten who claim that it does.

Comment: @GuyInchbald How about you start with one reference that says, changing the tailplane incidence changes the **stability** characteristics of the airplane. I bold stability because I don't mean **trim** or **trimmability**.

Comment: First book on my shelf. A.C. Kermode; "Mechanics of Flight", Pitman, 1972. pp. 269-70. Explicitly mentions both washout and tailplane incidence as significant factors affecting longitudinal stability. Your turn now.

Comment: @GuyInchbald Had you read the first paragraph on Longitudinal Stability, you would've realized the author is, in fact, talking about trimmability. "We have seen that an ordinary unswept wing with a cambered aerofoil section cannot  be balanced...and at the same time be stable...". See [this page](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/downwash-angle-zero-angle-attack-rate-change-downwash-angle-attack-determined-experimental-q47723406) for illustration of tailplane effect on Cm. As you can see, Cma is exactly the same across the different lines.

Comment: @GuyInchbald Or you can pick up "Dynamics of Flight", Etkins, 1996. The second chapter has all you need to know, especially Figure 2.16 (illustrated with elevator, but same idea with tailplane incidence). If you don't trust the equations, you can also pick up [AVL](http://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/avl/); it has a B737 model you can readily load. Try different tailplane incidences and see for yourself how much Cm slope changes.

Comment: Well, "the author is, in fact, talking about trimmability" might be more believable if he had not headed the subsection **Longitudinal Stability**. I think I'll just leave you to your imaginative interpretations of what others actually write.

Comment: @GuyInchbald I encourage you to either write down the longitudinal equations and see what effect tailplane incidence (it) has on the stability derivative, or try out the vortex lattice method I mentioned before. Don't take my word or anyone else's; let the math do the talking.

Comment: "But the aeroplane does these things. And if the theory does not give warranty to the practice, then it is the theory which is wrong." -- J.W. Dunne, lecture on *The Theory of the Dunne Aeroplane* to the Aeronautical Society of Great Britain, 1913. My advice to you is to lift your eyes and ask a real aeroplane designer what those equations actually mean.

Comment: @Guy, consider it a terminology issue, but the truth is, the tail incidence (or swept washout) _by itself_ indeed doesn't create stability. It is a _consequence_ of the need to balance (trim) the aircraft. Yes, it so happens (and it can be easily shown) that for a stable aircraft you will normally need a relatively lower tail incidence (or negative twist/washout), but what _creates_ stability (i.e.: "negative pitching moment slope") in the first place is _having_ a tail (or a certain wing shape).

Comment: @Zeus, that is back to front. You can trim a tailless straight wing with a conventional airfoil but it will still be unstable. The tail brings stability, for which its incidence must be within a narrow range. If the wing is in trim, the tail has zero incidence and does not contribute to trim, but does bring stability. The trim range dictates the CG range of the craft, not the other way round. Designers often work backwards from the desired CG range and that is how the subject is all too often taught - practically, but backwards.